# Basically Normal Dist question

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I'm a little rusty on my probability and would appreciate any help.
I think I have done the bulk of the work already anyway, but my question is:

If $X \sim LN(1,2)$ find $P(X>1)$

$X$ being LogNormal implies: $X = e^Y$, where $Y \sim N(1,2)$

So $P(X>1) \implies P(e^Y>1) \implies P(Y> ln(1)) \implies P(Y > 0)$

From here, we just need to consult our standard normal table?

But the issue is that $Y$ is not standard normal, so we need to convert it.

$Y = \frac{Z-\mu}{\sigma} \implies Y = \frac{Z-1}{\sqrt{2}}$

So we need to solve : $P(\frac{Z-1}{\sqrt{2}} > 0) \implies P(Z>1)$

Is this correct so far?

If so, now I get my standard normal table out, which finds values to the right of the $Z$ score. (I can also to the left, just with some basic algebraic manipualtion).

Consulting this: http://www.stat.ncsu.edu/people/osborne/courses/xiamen/normal-table.pdf

I scroll down to $P(Z>z) \space \text{where z} = 1.00 = .1587$.

However the answer in my text says $P(Y > 0) = 0.76$

Where is my error?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are normalising wrong. You should instead write

$$Y = \mu + \sigma Z$$

The rest looks fine

Comment: Thanks. So I tried it again, 
$ Z = \frac{Y-\mu}{\sigma}$
If we wants $P(Y>0) \implies P(\frac{Y-1}{\sqrt{2}} > \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}) \implies P(Z > 0) = P(Z<0) = 0.5$ 

What have I done wrong?

Comment: @piman314 $P(Y>0 ) = P(1+\sqrt 2 Z > 0) = P(Z > -1/\sqrt 2)$

Comment: Thanks, so $P(Z > -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) = P(Z < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) = 0.77935$?

The answer says $0.76$, but I'm assuming it's just to do with rounding?

Alternatively, $P(Z>-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) = 1-P(Z>0.707) = 0.77935$